# Creating new ASP.Net MVC project - Unit Test Dialog does not show up

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, unit-testing

When I create a New Project of type ASP.Net MVC Web Application, I expect the dialog for unit test applications to show up, but it does not. I cannot find the Unit Test App among the product types I can create either. How do I set up my VS so that the dialog shows up?

I have installed Visual Studio 2008, .Net Framework 3.5 SP1 and ASP.Net MVC Framework (Beta).

Comment: Did you install the professional version (or greater) of Visual Studio 2008?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out one of the problems were that I hadn't installed Testing Capabilities with my VS installation - running the installer and adding the feature made everything roll smoothly =)

Answer (score 4):

As @MrJavaGuy says, you need to install at least the Professional, not Express, version of VS2008.  Alternatively, you can install nUnit and/or TestDriven.Net and get unit testing capabilities.  Info on nUnit can be found at [http://www.nunit.org/](http://www.nunit.org/index.php) and TestDriven.Net at http://www.testdriven.net/.  I recommend TestDriven.Net even if you have the testing capabilities of Visual Studio baked in.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with Visual Web Developer Express, I found this blog.

http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/archive/2008/05/30/asp-net-mvc-preview-3-tooling-updates.aspx

I downloaded

http://www.box.net/shared/zmp0cdxsss

and that worked for me.. Not sure if this will sort your issue though. Best of luck with it.