# When starting a MVC project, no Test project is created

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, unit-testing

When creating a new MVC Project in VS2008 Professional (SP1 installed), I do not get prompted for a Unit Test project.

I have searched and found this solution ([Creating new ASP.Net MVC project - Unit Test Dialog does not show up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294117/creating-new-asp-net-mvc-project-unit-test-dialog-does-not-show-up)) BUT I have already installed the Testing Tools and still no Unit Test dialogue appears.

Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure you have .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 installed, and reinstall ASP.NET MVC 1.0.

Comment: have already done that. Still nothing. running Windows 7  if that makes any difference. Did not upgrade from Vista but did a clean install.

Comment: Windows 7 shouldn't make any difference. I'm also on Windows 7 (clean install the other day) and use VS2008 Pro SP1 and I see the unit test dialog each time I create a new mvc app.

Comment: Do you see any Test templates in the add new project dialog?

Comment: Paul, yes I do see Test Templates in the add new project dialogue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up formatting my pc, reinstalling Windows 7 and VS08 SP1 and MVC

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, the unit test project that is automagically added is just a class library project with the proper references added. Instead of worrying why the dialog doesn't pop up, add a class library project to your solution that references your testing framework. You'll end up with the results you want.

Comment: Thanks but I know how to create the test project manually, I just like it when it does create the Test Project automatically.